# Grails command on the sublime text 2 package not working

Tags: grails, sublimetext2, grails-2.0, sublimetext

I am using Sublime text 2 as an IDE for some Grails project, and to make things faster i have installed a new package using the package controle named : Shell Turtlestein.

This package helps to start command lines from the Sublime text itself, and whenever i do that from the new add-on it does not work and it gives me the following error :

```
/bin/sh: 1: grails: not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
```

While, if i did it from an external command line (Terminal) it works fine, if any of you guys have an experience with that package, what's the problem ?

P.S : i tried several options on the settings and nothing works

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are not getting sourced by sublime, therefore sublime has no idea where "grails" is. On some systems (e.g. osx) terminal paths are different from gui application paths.

There's actually a discussion regarding this on the [plugin's github page](https://github.com/misfo/Shell-Turtlestein/issues/2), with some solutions.